# Checkbox not activating in If/Else function

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm cobbling together pieces of a D&D character sheet in HTML and Javascript to practice what I'm learning and I'm having a little trouble with a checkbox on it. I've built a list of "Skills" that, when checked, are supposed to add in an additional bonus. I have it in an If/Else statement that at least is working enough to show the "Else" value, but once the checkbox is clicked nothing changes. So it seems the issue is in how I've set up the checkbox in the "If" statement. I'm still a beginner so I'm sure it's something obvious I've missed. Any help is appreciated!

```js
const abilityBonus = {
  strBonus: 3,
  dexBonus: 4,
  conBonus: 1,
  intBonus: 3,
  wisBonus: 2,
  chaBonus: 2,
  profBonus: 3,
};



// Test If/Else for checkbox to add Proficiency bonus, id as an arugement

function skillBonusTwo(ability, elementID) {
  const checkBox = document.getElementsByClassName('skill-box');
  const skillAbility = abilityBonus[ability];
  const totalBonus = skillAbility + abilityBonus.profBonus;
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    document.getElementById(elementID).value = totalBonus;
  } else {
    document.getElementById(elementID).value = skillAbility;
  }
}
skillBonusTwo('chaBonus', 'deception');
skillBonusTwo('chaBonus', 'intimidation');
skillBonusTwo('dexBonus', 'acrobatics');
skillBonusTwo('strBonus', 'athletics');
```

```html
<div id="skills">
      <ul id="skill-list">
        <lh>Skills</lh>
        <li>
          <label><input class="skill-box" id="acro-box" type="checkbox" />Acrobatics </label><input id="acrobatics" class="bonus-box" type="text" readonly="true"/>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label><input class="skill-box" type="checkbox" />Animal Handling</label><input id="animal-handling" class="bonus-box" type="text" readonly="true"/>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label><input class="skill-box" type="checkbox" />Arcana</label><input id="arcana" class="bonus-box" type="text" readonly="true"/>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label><input class="skill-box" type="checkbox" />Athletics</label><input id="athletics" class="bonus-box" type="text" readonly="true"/>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label><input class="skill-box" id="deception-box" type="checkbox" />Deception</label><input id="deception" class="bonus-box" type="text" readonly="true"/>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label><input class="skill-box" type="checkbox" />History</label><input id="history" class="bonus-box" type="text" readonly="true"/>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label><input class="skill-box" type="checkbox" />Insight</label><input id="insight" class="bonus-box" type="text" readonly="true"/>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label><input class="skill-box" type="checkbox" />Intimidation</label><input id="intimidation" class="bonus-box" type="text" readonly="true"/>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label><input class="skill-box" type="checkbox" />Investigation</label><input id="investigation" class="bonus-box" type="text" readonly="true"/>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label><input class="skill-box" type="checkbox" />Medicine</label><input id="medicine" class="bonus-box" type="text" readonly="true"/>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label><input class="skill-box" type="checkbox" />Nature</label><input id="nature" class="bonus-box" type="text" readonly="true"/>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label><input class="skill-box" type="checkbox" />Perception</label><input id="perception" class="bonus-box" type="text" readonly="true"/>
        </li>

        <li>
          <label><input class="skill-box" type="checkbox" />Performance</label><input id="performance" class="bonus-box" type="text" readonly="true"/>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label><input class="skill-box" type="checkbox" />Persuasion</label><input id="persuasion" class="bonus-box" type="text" readonly="true"/>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label><input class="skill-box" type="checkbox" />Religion</label><input id="religion" class="bonus-box" type="text" readonly="true"/>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label><input class="skill-box" type="checkbox" />Sleight of Hand</label><input id="sleight-of-hand" class="bonus-box" type="text" readonly="true"/>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label><input class="skill-box" type="checkbox" />Stealth</label><input id="stealth" class="bonus-box" type="text" readonly="true"/>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label><input class="skill-box" type="checkbox" />Survival</label><input id="survival" class="bonus-box" type="text" readonly="true"/>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName reutrns an HTMLCollection. You can't check if an htmlcollection is checked.

Comment: replace document.getElementsByClassName('skill-box') with => document.getElementsById('skill-box') and instead of class="skill-box" make it id="skill-box"

Comment: You haven't set up any event handlers, so your function never gets called.

If you set up a handler at the parent level of all the checkboxes, you can handle all checkbox clicks there.